# BTDropInController Paypal not open on selection showing "ERROR" in debug area

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

I'm Using BTDropInController for payment. On 3 Method of payment (Paypal, Venmo, By Card) from Access Control Panel. and Create TokenizationKey also generate.
Now in my Code Firstly import

```
#import <BraintreeDropIn/BraintreeDropIn.h>
#import <Braintree/BraintreeCore.h>
#import <Braintree/BraintreePayPal.h>
```

After implement Code dropIn showing but then i click on credit or debit card open another controller to get my card detail But then i click on paypal or venmo nothing happen just show "ERROR" in Debug area

```
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        } else if (result.cancelled) {
            NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
               //
            }];
        } else {
            // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
            // result.paymentOptionType
            // result.paymentMethod
            // result.paymentIcon
            // result.paymentDescription
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                //
            }];
        }
    }];
    [self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You can check this link, might be helpful to you. https://github.com/kumarpramod017/PKBraintreeHelper/blob/master/PKBraintreeHelper.swift

But it's a swift class, I hope you can under stand the swift code.

Comment: Instead of writing `NSLog(@"ERROR");` write `NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);` That should help you with figuring out what is going on.